# Temporary Onmouseover

Tags: javascript, onmouseover

Css "hover" selector applys a temporary style to an element, but it isn't definitive:

```
div:hover {
 background-color: red;
}
```

I can do the same thing with javascript but it is a bit complicate and impossible for several elements:

```
var elem = document.getElementsByTagName ("div")[0];

elem.onmouseover = function () {
 this.style.backgroundColor = "red";
}

elem.onmouseout = function () {
 this.style.backgroundColor = "transparent";
}
```

Is there a better way ? Something like this:

```
document.getElementsByTagName ("div")[0].ontemporarymouseover = function () { // LoL
 this.style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
```

Thanks

Comment: What does "isn't definitive" mean in this context?

Comment: Function `getElementByTagName` does not exist. There is only `getElementsByTagName`. It must be a reason of the issue you have.

Comment: Further to my previous comment, my gut says you are trying to use JavaScript to hack around a lack of understanding of the cascade: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#specificity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

// jQuery 'Temporary mouseevents'

```
$("element").bind
({
    mouseover:
        function ()
        {
        },
    mouseout:
        function ()
        {
        }
});

$("element").unbind('mouseover mouseout');
```

I hope this is a good approach for what you need.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no way to apply styles that go away by themselves.

Eventhough the CSS contains only one definition, it actually corresponds to the two state changes that triggers `onmouseover` and `onmouseout`. When the pointer enters the element, the `:hover` pseudo class is added to it making the CSS rule apply. When the pointer leaves the element, the `:hover` pseudo class is removed making the CSS rule no longer apply.

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript this behaviour can only be handled by listening to the `mouseover` and `mouseout` [DOM events](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOM_events), as you did in your second example. However it is recommended to handle hovering styles with CSS, as in your first example.

Comment: You can use the Javascript to set (and unset) a "hover" class, and then apply styles with CSS.

Comment: @Pointy: True... I meant "apart from that..." :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that if you use the jQuery JavaScript framework, you can do this:

```
$('div:first').hover(function(){
   $(this).css('background-color','red');
},function(){
   $(this).css('background-color','white');
});
```

Comment: No, that sets the background colour to 'red' onmouseover and onmouseout.